# How to retrieve dual batteries status?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, battery, batterylevel

```
 Dim power As PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus
 Dim percent As Single = power.BatteryLifePercent
```

or

```
PowerStatus power = SystemInformation.PowerStatus;
float percent = power.BatteryLifePercent;
```

(I would prefer a vb answer as that is what the application is written in but can convert so c# is fine if you dont know vb)

I understand that the above will give me the battery percentage remaining - BUT I have a tablet that is 'hot swappable' (it has a main battery then a small 5 minute battery that runs the tablet while you swap batteries on it) - how would I find the status of the second battery?

I am looking for something like `SystemInformation.PowerStatus(0)` but I have NO idea what I am actually trying to find and I must be having a Google block as I cannot find anything.

Comment: There's a WMI [`Win32_Battery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394074(v=vs.85).aspx) class if there's no managed access to this information.

Comment: Look at the page http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/Snippet/how_to_enumerate_batteries_using_wmi It provides full list of the information you can get from the WMI about the batteries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use WMI and Win32 to get the battery levels.

Try this:

```
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("Select * FROM Win32_Battery");

foreach (ManagementObject o in new ManagementObjectSearcher(query).Get())
{
    uint level = (uint)o.Properties["EstimatedChargeRemaining"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of multiple batteries, you can make use of WMI. Specifically, [Win32_Battery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.However, this will be a bit slower than using `PowerStatus` class.

Comment: Speed not an issue - will only be polling it every 2 minutes or so - just that my application is full screen so covers the status!